# Need Assistance With Blazor and LibMan to install Bootstrap and associated components (i.e., Popper and jQuery)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, blazor, libman

I am working on a Blazor project in which I am using Bootstrap; which, of course, requires jQuery and Popper for the tooltips and popovers to work.

Originally, I just "manually" downloaded the required files:

- jQuery
- Popper
- Bootstrap (css and js)

and put them where they need to go:

- wwwroot/css
- wwwroot/js

The structure of `wwwroot` looked like this:

```
/wwwroot
|
|- css/
|  |
|  |- bootstrap/
|  |
|  `- site.css
|
|- images/
|
`- js/
   |
   |- bootstrap/
   |
   |- jquery/
   |
   |- popper/
   |
   |- BootstrapJavascript.js
   |
   `- JavaScript.js
```

However, the "powers that be" have decided they would like to make this more efficient and automatic, so I now need to use LibMan to install everything, and I am using this method:

```
Solution Explorer -> Project -> Add -> Client-Side Library...
```

So, everything went smoothly when installing, however I am having trouble with Popper. After installing, `wwwroot` now looks like this:

```
/wwwroot
|
|- css/
|  |
|  |- bootstrap*.*
|  |
|  `- site.css
|
|- images/
|
|- js/
|  |
|  |- bootstrap*.*
|  |
|  |- cjs/
|  |
|  |- esm/
|  |
|  |- umd/
|  |
|  `- BootstrapJavascript.js
|
`- scss/
```

And I am receiving errors indicating that the application cannot find certain libraries or components of libraries.

Originally, when using LibMan to install Popper, LibMan wanted to put Popper here:

```
wwwroot/lib/popper.js/
```

However, I elected to put Popper in:

```
wwwroot/js/
```

Also, on Bootstraps website, they instruct to pre-load the ability to use tooltips and popovers like this:

```
// For Bootstrap's Tooltips
// https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/tooltips/
const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl))


// For Bootstrap's Popovers
// https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/popovers/
const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl))
```

Which I have in my BootstrapJavascript.js file.

Some of the errors I am getting:

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at https://localhost:5003/js/cjs/popper.js:7:23
```

Error at `App.razor:line 48`, which is in here:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/cjs/popper.js"); // THIS IS LINE #48
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/bootstrap.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/BootstrapJavaScript.js");
    }
}
```

The application was working "perfectly" when I was hand installing Bootstrap, Popper, and jQuery, now it is not.

What do I need to do to get this working like when I was hand-installing?

---

---

**EDIT:**

**libman.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "library": "jquery@3.6.1",
      "destination": "wwwroot/js/jquery/"
    },
    {
      "library": "popper.js@2.11.6",
      "destination": "wwwroot/js/popper/"
    },
    {
      "library": "twitter-bootstrap@5.2.2",
      "destination": "wwwroot/"
    }
  ]
}
```

**App.razor**

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/jquery/jquery.min.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/popper/cjs/popper.min.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/bootstrap.min.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/BootstrapJavaScript.js");
    }
}
```

**_Host.cshtml:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>

...

    </div>
    <script>
        var blackpearlScript = document.createElement('script');
        blackpearlScript.setAttribute('src', '/js/JavaScript.js');
        document.head.appendChild(blackpearlScript);
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, I don't know why you put your js files in `App.razor`, I think it is better ot add them in your `MainLayout.razor` or `_Host.cshtml`:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Second**, I don't think that you need to include Popper because Bootstrap has already this library in `bootstrap.bundle.js`, see this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/). You can add this file like this:

Solution Explorer -> right click on Project -> Add -> Client-Side Library -> twitter-bootstrap -> choose specific files -> js -> bootstrap.bundle.min.js.

**Please note** that the files will be added in `lib` folder, if you want to change the location, then you need to change your `libman.json` and I don't think that necessary to change location, just keep them in `lib`folder.

**Then**, your script in `MainLayout.razor` or `_Host.cshtml` will be:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/BootstrapJavaScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was having issues with Bootstrap, Popper, and jQuery loading so I found the solution of loading them dynamically within App.razor. Nevertheless, your post "fixed" me. I had no idea I needed to use `bootstrap.bundle.js`, so I kept pointing at `bootstrap.min.js`, and that is where the problem was. When I pointed at the bundle, everything worked again. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to fully explain the general solution that I use in my projects. Probably, your problem are in the definitions of js and css entries.

First of all install `LibMan` with the below command:

```
dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli
```

The next step is to add a file called libman.json inside the project. To add this file, just enter the following command in the command prompt:

```
libman init
```

As you can see, we can also specify the package receiving source, which is set to cdnjs by default, and is actually a Content Delivery Network (CDN) for countless client-side packages. We can also enter our required packages in the libraries array. Even for each package, we can override the provider.

```
`{"version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
  "libraries": [

  ]
}`
```

Now, you can get the Jquery, Bootstrap and so on by following command:

```
libman install bootstrap --provider unpkg --destination wwwroot/lib/bootstrap
libman install jquery --provider unpkg --destination wwwroot/lib/jquery
```

Finally, the libman.json file will have below structure:

```
`{"version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "",
  "libraries": [
 {
  "provider": "cdnjs",
  "library": "twitter-bootstrap@5.1.3",
  "destination": "wwwroot/lib/twitter-bootstrap/"
},    
{
  "provider": "unpkg",
  "library": "jquery@3.6.0",
  "destination": "wwwroot/lib/jquery/"
}
  ]
}`
```

After receiving its client-side packages, we will add the relevant entries to the Blazor Server application's Pages `\_Layout.cshtml` file (or to the Blazor WASM application's
`wwwroot/index.html` file).

```
    <head>
        <base href="~/" />      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/twitter- 
            bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        ..........
        ..........
        <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>        
        <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    </body>
```

We define the entry of the css file in the head section and the js file before closing the body tag and of course before `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` in Blazor Server. There is no need to mention the `wwwroot` starting folder; Because `base href` is defined, it points to this folder.

You can also use the `libman restore` command to reinstall the packages; In this case, just like Nuget, the packages will be downloaded from the libman.json file from the relevant provider and added to the project.

One additional point: You can modify the program's csproj file as follows to automatically run the libman restore command before the build:

```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <Target Name="DebugEnsureLibManEnv" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
        <!-- Ensure libman is installed -->
        <Exec Command="libman --version" ContinueOnError="true">
          <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
        </Exec>
        <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="libman is required to build and run this project. To continue, please run `dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli`, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
        <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'libman'. This may take several minutes..." />
        <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" Command="libman restore" />
      </Target>
    </Project>
```

**EDIT:**

According to your comment and edited question:

First, The bootstrap package is installed inside the root of `wwwroot`.

```
{
  "library": "twitter-bootstrap@5.2.2",
  "destination": "wwwroot/"
}
```

However, it is referenced in the `JS` folder.

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/bootstrap.min.js");
```

Second, please remove the line below from _Host.cshtml:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

I suggest that you try to refer to the `_Host.cshtml` file instead of referring to the `OnAfterRenderAsync` method, such as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

You can do the same for other libraries, such as `Popper`.

> Originally, when using LibMan to install Popper, LibMan wanted to put Popper here

Please try this too. It means the default installation path (`/lib`) in the `libman` folder.

I think that all the differences between the code of my project that is running now and the code of your project were these things.

Comment: So, I believe I already had everything in place that you mentioned here. See my Edits above for my version of what you listed here.

Comment: Dear bro, I think they are slightly different. I edited the end of my answer according to your question.